# Changing a HTML <p> to a string-value from an object

Tags: javascript, html

I am sure this has been asked before but I am such a beginner at this that I dont think I would recognize the answer even if I happened stumbled upon it.

I am wondering why my code is not doing what it is meant to. It is supposed to take a value from the object event1 and copy it into the HTML p-tags and button-tags. Am I trying to do something completely ignorant?

```js
var event1 = {
 situation: "Du befinner dig hemma i soffan. Det är mörkt utomhus och TVn är påslagen. På soffbordet ser du ett tomt glas och en flaska vodka.",
  val1: "1. Stäng av TVn",
  val2: "2. Gå utomhus",
  val3: "3. Fyll glaset med vodka";
};

document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = event1.situation();
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = event1.val1();
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = event1.val2();
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = event1.val3();
```

```html
<p id="event"></p>

<p>Vad vill du göra?</p>

<button type="button" id="choice1"></button>
<button type="button" id="choice2"></button>
<button type="button" id="choice3"></button>
```

[My Code in JSFiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4rT5.png)

Also an extra question: Can I nest objects inside objects or is that not possible?

Comment: Post the code in the question. Stackoverflow has the same features as jsfiddle. Use the snipplet button.

Comment: I did, posted a picture. Cant see the link?

Comment: Image is bad...We can not copy text in an image...

Comment: Aight, added the code. Hope its better now : )

Comment: situation , val1, val2, val3 are not a methods. You have a semicolon in your object. The console gives you the errors.

Comment: So delete the () ? I just tried that but it still doesnt work. :0

Comment: 'ERROR {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"`

Comment: Where is the console in jsfiddle? I cannot find it.

Comment: In your browser or click the run button in your question...

Comment: Wow, you mean the devconsole? I am not joking when I say that i tried that before asking the question and it gave me nothing in response. I try it once now and it tells me exactly what the problem is....

Comment: Thanks stranger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a syntax error in the object after `val3` (the semicolon), and you would need the parenthesis if you were calling a function, but you are just referencing a value, so it is not appropriate.

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
var event1 = {
  situation: "Du befinner dig hemma i soffan. Det är mörkt utomhus och TVn är påslagen. På soffbordet ser du ett tomt glas och en flaska vodka.",
  val1: "1. Stäng av TVn",
  val2: "2. Gå utomhus",
  val3: "3. Fyll glaset med vodka"
};

document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = event1.situation;
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = event1.val1;
document.getElementById("choice2").textContent = event1.val2;
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = event1.val3;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I thought it was self explanatory, but here was the prob... There was a syntax error in the object after `val3` (the semicolon), and you would need the parens if you were calling a function, but you are just referencing a value, so it is not appropriate. Hope that clarifies everything.

Comment: Yeah I came straight from C# where you need to end with ().I couldve helped myself if the dev-console hadnt fooled me.  Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

first never close a object second event1.wherever is not a function try this way :)

```js
var event1 = {
 situation: "Du befinner dig hemma i soffan. Det är mörkt utomhus och TVn är påslagen. På soffbordet ser du ett tomt glas och en flaska vodka.",
  val1: "1. Stäng av TVn",
  val2: "2. Gå utomhus",
  val3: "3. Fyll glaset med vodka"
};

document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = event1.situation;
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = event1.val1;
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = event1.val2;
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = event1.val3;

console.log(event1.situation)
```

```html
<p id="event"></p>

<p>Vad vill du göra?</p>

<button type="button" id="choice1"></button>
<button type="button" id="choice2"></button>
<button type="button" id="choice3"></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/GmWJYR).

Updated code:

```
var event1 = {
     situation: "Du befinner dig hemma i soffan. Det är mörkt utomhus och TVn är påslagen. På soffbordet ser du ett tomt glas och en flaska vodka.",
       val1: "1. Stäng av TVn",
       val2: "2. Gå utomhus",
       val3: "3. Fyll glaset med vodka"
}

document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = event1.situation
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = event1.val1
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = event1.val2
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = event1.val3
```

Errors in original code: semi-colon at end of line 5. Semi-colons are illegal in objects. Commas and colons only.
References to object were using a 'method' style of syntax, whereas the contents of the object are properties.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: agreed, but epascarello has commented above which provides the context amicably.

Comment: Without that context in your answer itself, the answer is of lower quality than it could be.